# Node.js application works on heroku but not if downloaded from github

Tags: node.js, git, github, heroku, npm

I have this project: https://github.com/FablabRUC/apiproject

This project is pushed via git from my local computer to Github. The project is able to run on Heroku if I deploy the local files. The problem is that when I download the Github project and try the exact same deploy strategy the result is different. The downloaded files are running fine locally, but Heroku don't like them. Is Github adding something I don't know of? Or what do you think could be the problem?

This is the Heroku logs from the project when its downloaded via github:

```
2020-06-01T12:02:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-01T12:02:10.653378+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-01T12:02:14.703102+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-01T12:02:14.703115+00:00 app[web.1]: > api_fablab_deploy@1.0.0 start /app
2020-06-01T12:02:14.703120+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-06-01T12:02:14.703120+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639089+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639116+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639116+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639116+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639117+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './User'
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639118+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639119+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/user/UserController.js
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639119+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639120+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639122+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639123+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639123+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639124+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639124+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/user/UserController.js:7:12)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639125+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639125+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639126+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639126+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639127+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639127+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639128+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:6:22)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639128+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639129+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639129+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639129+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14) {
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639130+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639131+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/user/UserController.js', '/app/app.js', '/app/server.js' ]
2020-06-01T12:02:15.639132+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-06-01T12:02:15.649939+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-06-01T12:02:15.650376+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-06-01T12:02:15.652026+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! api_fablab_deploy@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-06-01T12:02:15.652295+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-06-01T12:02:15.652555+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-06-01T12:02:15.652774+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the api_fablab_deploy@1.0.0 start script.
2020-06-01T12:02:15.652987+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-06-01T12:02:15.684689+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-01T12:02:15.684745+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-06-01T12:02:15.684883+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-01T12_02_15_662Z-debug.log
2020-06-01T12:02:15.770591+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-01T12:02:15.821633+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-01T12:02:15.824137+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-01T12:02:18.080879+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-01T12:02:20.896285+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-01T12:02:20.896313+00:00 app[web.1]: > api_fablab_deploy@1.0.0 start /app
2020-06-01T12:02:20.896314+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-06-01T12:02:20.896314+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536306+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536351+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536351+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536352+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536352+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './User'
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536352+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536353+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/user/UserController.js
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536354+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536354+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536355+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536355+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536356+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536356+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536357+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/user/UserController.js:7:12)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536357+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536358+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536358+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536358+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536358+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536359+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536359+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:6:22)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536359+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536359+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536360+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536360+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14) {
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536360+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536361+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/user/UserController.js', '/app/app.js', '/app/server.js' ]
2020-06-01T12:02:21.536361+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-06-01T12:02:21.544004+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-06-01T12:02:21.544293+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-06-01T12:02:21.545512+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! api_fablab_deploy@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-06-01T12:02:21.545659+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-06-01T12:02:21.545834+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-06-01T12:02:21.545985+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the api_fablab_deploy@1.0.0 start script.
2020-06-01T12:02:21.546113+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-06-01T12:02:21.564586+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-01T12:02:21.564995+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-06-01T12:02:21.565128+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-01T12_02_21_548Z-debug.log
2020-06-01T12:02:21.646999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-01T12:02:21.691304+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-01T12:02:37.000133+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-earth-53207.herokuapp.com request_id=9c562652-4f24-476c-8fa7-ac52d7d3e4d7 fwd="212.237.134.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-01T12:02:37.318817+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-earth-53207.herokuapp.com request_id=4163db93-a422-4fb9-a129-0d1e3b10b9ae fwd="212.237.134.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Compare the directories you have stored in git versus the directories you have locally. I suspect you have build files or similar locally, which is why locally works but not from github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely caused by case sensitivity. On line 7 of UserController.js you require `./User` but the file is titled `user.js`. Heroku is likely case insensitive, whereas your file system is not. I imagine capitalizing the file name, or changing the require to all lowercase should resolve your issue here.

Comment: This helped me with the problem. I don't understand why this typo wasn't fixed with a: 

git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git push heroku master

I needed to visit github and edit the file name manually, instead of just fixing the filename and then push a commit.